# loop a statistic test

Tags: r

I' m quite new in R. I have two data.frame that look like this:

DF1

> ```
>  List_name     Smokers   Not_smokers    
>   List1          30         100
>   List2          10          50
>   List3          3           10
>   List4          12          85
>   List5          56          60
>   List6          90         120
> ```

DF2

> ```
>  List_name      Male       Female    
>   List1          23          123
>   List2          45          654
>   List3          35          110
>   List4          145         850
>   List5          89          234
>   List6          56          765
> ```

I would like to apply a prop.test between for ex: the first line of DF2 and each single line of DF1 and then the second line of DF2 and each single line of DF1, then the third line of DF2 and each single line of DF1 and so on until the end of all the lines of DF2. So, since  DF1 has dimension: 100(rows)X2(columns) and DF2 has 30(rows)X2(columns) finally I would have 30X100 tests so 3000 tests.

What I tried is the following (using a function from another posted question):

```
for (i in 1:length(DF2)){ 
   test <- apply(DF1, 1, function(x) prop.test(rbind(x, as.numeric(DF2[[i]]), correct=TRUE,  alternative="two.sided", conf.level=.99))
}
```

But it doesn't work. Obviously there are errors that I'm not able to solve due to the fact that I'm a beginner. Another issue is that each test I perform will be saved in a separate variable and/or printed on a separate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your DF1 and DF2 objects are data.frame. Because you use DF2 as a list...

```
DF1 <- data.frame(Smokers=c(30, 10, 3, 12, 56, 90), Not_smokers=c(100, 50, 10, 85, 60, 120))
DF2 <- data.frame(M=c(23, 45, 35, 145, 89, 56), F=c(123, 654, 110, 850, 234, 765))

test <- vector("list", dim(DF1)[1]*dim(DF2)[1])
k=1
for (i in 1:dim(DF2)[1]){
for(j in 1:dim(DF1)[1]){
    test[[k]] <- prop.test(rbind(as.numeric(DF1[j,]), as.numeric(DF2[i,])), correct=TRUE, alternative="two.sided", conf.level=.99)
    k=k+1
}
}

# the chi-square test produce warnings   
warnings()
```

Comment: Hi David! Thank you a lot for your help. I solved the Warnings by myself. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for beginners is with 2 loops

```
DF1 <- read.table(text='List_name Smokers Not_smokers 
 List1 30 100
 List2 10 50
 List3 3 10
 List4 12 85
 List5 56 60
 List6 90 120',header=T)

DF2 <- read.table(text='List_name Male Female 
 List1 23 123
 List2 45 654
 List3 35 110
 List4 145 850
 List5 89 234
 List6 56 765', header=T)

test <- NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(DF2)) { 
 for (j in 1:nrow(DF1)) {
  test <- c(test,prop.test(c(DF1[j,2], DF2[i,2]),c(DF1[j,3]+DF1[j,2], DF2[i,3]+DF2[i,2]), correct=TRUE,  alternative="two.sided", conf.level=.99))
 }
}
```

The test I maid is quiet different of that in your question, but I think that it is the one you need (I'm testing if the proportion of smoker/no smoker is the same as male/female)

Edit:

For save the results in a list:

```
test <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(DF2)) { 
 for (j in 1:nrow(DF1)) {
  test[[length(test)+1]] <- prop.test(c(DF1[j,2], DF2[i,2]),c(DF1[j,3]+DF1[j,2], DF2[i,3]+DF2[i,2]), correct=TRUE,  alternative="two.sided", conf.level=.99)
 }
}
```

Comment: Rcoster's advice is solid.  You can add `print(test)` to each loop to see the results.  Alternatively, the result of `prop.test` is a list.  You could first initialize an empty list of the right size, before the loop, with `results <- vector("list", nrow(DF1)*nrow(DF2))`.  Then change `test <- `  to results[[I*j]] <- ` and the list will be filled in as the loops go.

Comment: result[[i*j]] will subscribe some results (like i = 1,j = 2 and j = 2,i = 1), result[[length(result) + 1]] should work if you set results as an empty list in the beggining